# How to save all WhatsApp messages and media unencrypted?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I'm planning to quit Whatsapp but I would like to save an unencrypted record of my messages plus all the media files that are still on my phone. From existing solutions, I found some shortcomings such as no exporting of group chats or a 40k message limit. What is the method that best circumvents these limitations?

While I have the android app, I'd be open for a Mac or PC solution.